# Меню и виджет на вордпресс сайте расползлись без стилей

Tags: wordpress

https://stereoschool.ru/ - верхнее меню и виджет Профессиональные курсы ниже на странице неправильно отображаются. Консоль браузера показывает что файлы css не подключены net::ERR_ABORTED 404, точнее, в них старый поддомен https://sproducer.stereoschool.ru/, с которого перенесли сайт.
[image: См. скрин.]
При поиске урла в строке  по файлам сайта ничего не находится.
Ссылки заменил через sql запрос в базе данных.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Не правильно перенёс сайт. А своим  "заменил через sql запрос" вообще поломал БД. См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562